# Gmail API stopped retrieving correct emails for specific date

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I've written code to retrieve labels and then depending on a selected label - return a list of emails from Gmail API. But what I've noticed is that it worked perfectly fine for a few requests, and then at some point my application crashed with `Http Host` something or rather error (It was truncated), I restarted my application - and it never worked as expected ever since.

The code snippets:

Retrieves all Labels:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetAllLabels(string userId) {
    Dictionary<string, string> labels = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    try {
        ListLabelsResponse response = _service.Users.Labels.List(userId).Execute();
        foreach (var label in response.Labels) {
            labels.Add(label.Id, label.Name);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }

    return labels;
```

Part of the code that retrieves the messages:

```
    var result = new List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message>();
    UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = _service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
    request.LabelIds = labelId;
    request.Q = query;

    do {
        try {
            ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
```

I can see that `labelId` and `query` do get set to correct values: `Label_5`, `after:2017/2/16 before:2017/2/17`

Because if I look up what Label_5 is - it returns my correct label, and if I copy-paste the date filter into the search bar - it does return correct emails, for 16th.

But instead of retrieving data for 16th like it was before - now all of a sudden the emails that have been received on 16th now only get returned if I pass in `after:2017/2/15 before:2017/2/16` through the application, and the emails requested for 16th: `after:2017/2/16 before:2017/2/17` now return null (Again, this only happens in application **NOT** in Gmail UI). That makes no sense what so ever to me, of why all of a sudden it would change behaviour like that.

Seems like it has something to do with API itself rather than my code, is there a workaround this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether the API call itself was modified on Google's end? Can you post some errors that you are getting? Also, make sure to check whether you've probably hit the allowed requests with the Gmail API.

Comment: Have you tried using seconds since epoch instead? `after:1487116800 before:1487203200 ` instead of `after:2017/2/15 before:2017/2/16`.

Comment: Hi Angelo, I don't receive any errors from Google API, just comes back with null value for messages. How do I check if I've hit that limit? Thank you.

Comment: Hello Tholle, I've changed my code to calculate the seconds, and it seems to work so far, but I have ran it a day later, so I don't know if it will keep working or it will break again :/ If you could please post it as answer at least I can check it if things will work smoothly for the next couple of days